# Uber: planned vs unplanned pricing

Tags: uber, florida, orlando

When buying airfare, planning & buying in advance is preferable because of cost savings.

Is the same true with Uber?  Apparently I can schedule a 50 mile trip to the Jacksonville, FL airport in advance, but I wonder if last minute pricing is better.  I suspect that the same applies to a 90 mile trip to MCO

Comment: Last I checked, you get no price guarantees for advance booking? Or any guarantees really.

Comment: Last I check you also pay an extra fee for advance booking

Answer (score 4):

Based off my own testing the answer is **No**, it's not cheaper.

Normal price for tonight is $53.81 for regular UberX or $50.19 with Wait&Save, when going from downtown Seattle to Seattle airport:

[image]

But if I schedule a ride for 4am in April, the price increases to $71.95:

[image]

I've tried times other than 4am too and they're even more expensive. You can try it yourself for your own destination but I'm pretty sure it would always be more expensive.

Also note that Uber [doesn’t guarantee](https://www.uber.com/en-FR/blog/schedule-rides-in-advance-with-uber-reserve/) a driver will actually be available at the time you’ve pre-booked. I suspect that internally all they do is send out a ride request 10 minutes prior to your scheduled departure, without actually keeping a driver “on call” for your specific ride.

> Uber doesn’t guarantee that a driver will accept your ride request. Your ride is confirmed once you receive your driver details.

Comment: I have the same experience. Makes sense that _blocking_ a driver so they'll be available at a specific time costs more than the dynamically-fill-every-availability strategy they usually have.

Comment: @deceze But do they actually block a driver? I thought they just delay the request and send it out automatically a few minutes before.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Even so, they’ll have to make sure somebody will actually be available to send the request to. In high demand times when all drivers would be busy, they have to keep *someone* back to ensure they’re not too far away or busy. That’s what you’re paying for there. If it’s not busy at that time anyway, it’s a plus for Uber for getting more money for the same service. If all drivers would have been busy at that time, it’s a plus for you for not having to wait.

Comment: @deceze "Uber doesn’t guarantee that a driver will accept your ride request." https://www.uber.com/en-FR/blog/schedule-rides-in-advance-with-uber-reserve/

Comment: @lambshaanxy That point is very unclear. It only pertains the point about airports…?! If you couldn't _rely_ on your booked-in-advance ride because the driver might decline it last minute, then what's the point of it at all?

Comment: @deceze there is no point, yes. Though I'm sure its useful to some people who prefer to pre-book things in advance.

Comment: @deceze That's exactly what I'm saying: there is no point, it's just marketing.